# Batch - Execute Macros from command line

Tags: csv, batch-file, macros, cmd

I have a macro done by **LibreOffice Calc** it's a french version of OpenOffice. 
This macro opens a csv file without the dialog box. But I'd like to execute it via Batch.

The ideia is, use `system()` commmand in matlab to run this macro.

This macro is in addressed as  **Importcsv.ods --> Standard --> Module1 --> CSVOpen**
How should I put the complete address of the file, and where put the name of the csv file I want to open?

Many thanks,

Bruno

PS: I'd forgot something. I want to run this in *Calc* and there, do anything I want. Because this file will be sabed in  **xls** to be used in SolidWorks (CAD software).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've continued looking for it, and I found an answer to execute the macro.
We should open the repertory in cmd where is the file with the macro ,put the address of the **exe**,  write the name of it and the reference of the macros. I'll do an example:

`"C:\Program Files\OpenOffice.org 3\program\soffice.exe" FileName.ods "macro:///Standard.Module1.MacroName"`

if wanted directly from matlab, is just use the `system('')` command.

Answer (score 0):

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\OpenOffice 4\program\swriter.exe" -invisible "macro:///Standard.Module1.Main"
```

or from another source

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\OpenOffice 4\program\swriter.exe" -nologo -norestore -nolockcheck "macro:///Standard.Module1.Main"
```